# How to loop two variables simultaneously in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle21c

I have two tables have relationship to each other, an owner and an owned table, now I want to query both tables and return data from these two tables. But when I try to query results from two tables, the select will return extra data to me.

Below shows how I create the two tables

```
create table owner( 
    id         integer not null, 
    name        varchar2(22) not null, 
    primary key (id) );

create table owned( 
    id         integer not null, 
    restaurantId       char(10) not null, 
    resgisterCode      integer not null, 
    primary key (id, restaurantId), 
    foreign key (aid) references owner(id), 
    foreign key (restaurantId) references restaurant(restaunrantId) );
```

I want to get the owner name and the corresponding resgisterCode and this is what I tried

```
Cursor get_ownerId_registerCode(OwnerID owner.id%type) is
select owner.name, owned.resgisterCode INTO name, code from owner, owned where owner.id = Id AND owned.aid = owner.aid Order By owned.registerCode desc;
```

Comment: In table `owned`, there is `id` column which is a part of primary key. In foresight key definition, there is `aid`. What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Well, code you posted can't work anyway (not that it "returns extra data") as INTO clause can't be used in a cursor declaration.

Problem you specified ("extra data") is due to *wrong* parameter name. This is what you did:

```
where owner.id = Id   
                 -- 
                 this is a parameter, isn't it?
                 (you should've posted the whole PL/SQL procedure to avoid confusion)
```

For Oracle, it is just the same as if you used `where owner.id = owner.id` or even `where 1 = 1` so query returned *everything*. You shouldn't name parameters the same as column names - precede their names with a prefix, e.g. `par_id` or `p_id` or whatever you find appropriate.

Apart from that, I'd suggest you to use a cursor `FOR` loop because - if you do -  final code is much simpler as you don't have to open the cursor, fetch from it, pay attention about exiting the loop or closing the cursor - Oracle does that for you.

Therefore, consider something like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_test (par_id in owner.id%type) is
begin
  for cur_r in (select owner.name, owned.resgisterCode 
                -- INTO name, code -- no INTO clause in cursor!    
                from owner join owned on owned.aid = owner.aid
                where owner.id = par_id    -- parameter is used here
                order by owned.registercode desc
               )
    dbms_output.put_Line(cur_r.name ||', '|| cur_r.registercode);
  end loop;
end;
/
```